# Is there anyway to get the memory dump of the running ecs task?

Tags: .net-core, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, memory-dump

I have a situation wherein the running Fargate ECS task is consuming more memory and when I run the solution locally I don't see any difference in memory consumption.
docker in the Fargate task running the dotnet core application. When running locally, JetBrains dotMemory is showing the memory consumption along with garbage collection and everything going fine there. So want to know if there is any way we can get the memory dump of the running ECS task with that I can investigate what's actually going wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you just need a shell in the container for that or are you looking for something more specific? ECS (both Fargate and EC2) has introduced support for [ECS exec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html) recently.